# How do I upload my existing Ubuntu VM to Google Cloud?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I would like to have exactly the same settings and configuration as well as all files. I have tried uploading and importing both an OVA file, as well as importing an image, putting it into a disk and then making a cloud VM boot up from there. However, when i SSH into it, there is absolutely nothing, all settings are gone and there are no files. What am I doing wrong? I am using Google Cloud Platform, and I use oracle virtualbox for the VM i want to upload.
The VM is an ubuntu server 20.04 and contains wordpress as well as netconfigs, and I would like both the wordpress and terminal to be accessed remotely. Am I doing it the right way?
Thanks!

- Wanted to upload the OVA file, was expecting a VM to boot exactly like my local VM. Booted up as if it were a new one with no settings or files.
- Uploaded and imported the local VM disk, cloud VM still turned on as if it was a new one with no files or settings.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer files to Compute Engine VM instances, different options are available depending on the workstation OS and the target VM instance OS. Please see below official documentation.

[Link_1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#upload-to-the-vm)

Once the files are transferred to Compute Engine VM instances, please refer to the below official documentation to boot from the newly created instance.

[Link_2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/standard-ssh)

As you are trying to connect to it using the SSH , please refer to the official documentation as mentioned below.

[Link_3](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser)

Hope the above information is helpful to you.

Comment: @Anthony is your issue resolved? let me know if you need any additional help.